# Calculated field for Percentage difference in data studio

Tags: looker-studio, calculated-field

I need to have the percentage difference between different time duration for the same raw data coming from Analytics. Unable to do so as metrics from data source doesn't consist any time duration and in order to create calculated field I'm supposed to use the metrics from the data source. How shall I go about creating the percentage difference in this scenario?

Feel free to ask follow up.

Comment: Hi Smeet. Can you provide more information / examples? What does your data look like? What have you tried already? What does the expected outcome look like?

Comment: Hey Bobby, So I have grouped different KPIs metrics into two time period, Lets just consider P1 and P2 for time stamp and Sessions as metric for better understanding. Now I wanted to create a calculated metric for sessions which shows only percentage difference between P1 and P2. Now I've tried blending data of two scorecards but data studio doesn't allow data blending for different time period. So now my basic expectation from this is to create a scorecard or any chart which is able to showcase percentage difference between the different time stamp for the same metric.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you can't do a calculated metric to achieve what you are after. The only option available is "comparison to period" but I'm guessing from what you've put there that it isn't possible either.

The only way to achieve this would be by organising you data in your data source to be something like

```
Date | metric value | metric value to compare to
```

But I appreciate this may not be as flexible as you'd like